# name.bb appears above picture when using includegraphics

Tags: xetex, includegraphics

I've tried adding a picture using:

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \textbf{bbb}\par\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{schematOgolny.png}
    \captionof{figure}{sth}
    \label{aaa}
\end{figure}
```

In the result I've got this:

[image: result from xelatex]

XeLaTeX added text `schematOgolny.bb` above the picture. This does not however happens when I use PDFLaTeX

[image: result from pdflatex]

I'm a bit hesitant towards using PDFLaTeX because for some reason utf8 is not supported (and I need utf8).

My question is how can I get rid of that extra text in XeLaTeX?

**SOLUTION:**

I had defined `\graphicspath` for `graphicx library, which caused the issue. Thanks for @Teepeemm for pointing me in the right direction

**EDIT:**

This is minimal reproducable example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{capt-of}
% Problematic line (path does not need to actually exist):
\graphicspath{ { C:/sth/PracInż/obrazy/ } }
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \textbf{bbb}\par\medskip
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{schematOgolny.png}
    % Any picture will do
    \captionof{figure}{sth}
    \label{aaa}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm skeptical that this would actually happen.  If you have a file that has only `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{graphicx}\begin{document}` and then your posted code and then `\end{document}`, do you still have the `.bb` occur?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us help you by providing a minimal compilable code example (MWE).

Comment: Could you show us your `.log` file?

Comment: without any example code it is hard to guess but I would suspect an incorrect option to the graphics package

Comment: Also why are you using captionof inside a figure? That looks wrong

Comment: No - in a new document `.bb` does not occurs. I've checked head of document and commenting `graphicspath` have solved the issue.

Comment: @daleif The reason for that is that when you do `\includegraphics[angle=270,...]...` and `\captionof` is outside of figure then it might end up on a different page then the actual figure. Placing it inside figure prevents that.

Comment: @Miku nope, that has nothing to do with it. Captionof is to be used in situations where caption cannot pickup the type automatically, for example in a center env, if you have both a table and a figure in the same, say, figure, float, in this case it makes no sense as the figure environment already provides the type for caption. In general you should let all figures float

Comment: @Miku your `\graphicspath` had a space in it I would guess? So the error is in code that you did not show so only you can answer the question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No, there were no spaces, but there was letter `ż`. It might have had been that (but then why did PDFLaTeX worked fine, but XeLaTeX not?)

Comment: If you had provided a test file we could have run it and debugged but as you didn't I can't really say.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added contents of file that causes this problem in edit section. Actuall path in `graphicspath` can be anything

Comment: I will answer once the question is re-opened, but it was, as I guessed, spaces in the graphics path: this will work `\graphicspath{ {C:/sth/PracInż/obrazy/} }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spaces are not stripped from segments in the graphics path so your specification causes Tex to try to load

```
C:/sth/PracInż/obrazy/ schematOgolny.png
```

and the space terminates TeX's primitive filename reader and things go wrong.

Use

```
\graphicspath{ {C:/sth/PracInż/obrazy/} }
```

Comment: I did what you said and it solved problem. Thanks :)